# How to skip samples in an audio buffer on iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I'm trying to skip or shorten silence on audio playback on iOS. Using RemoteIO, I'm using the following code snippet for the logic of removing silence. However, it's not working correctly. Based on the code, I would expect the silences to be removed from the `samples` and for the audio to at minimum play faster (since samples would be removed). However, instead I get weird pops/clicks on occasion and the audio timing is the same (nothing is skipped forward as if silence was removed).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is this the wrong approach for doing this?

```
// original samples are stored in renderBufferList
// loop through the samples and replace anything less than amplitudeThreshold 
// with the next "non-silent" sample

SInt16 *samples = renderBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
int sampleCount = renderBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize / sizeof(SInt16);
int currentSampleIndex = 0;
int amplitudeThreshold = 15;
int channels = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i+=channels) {
    SInt16 sampleL = samples[i];
    SInt16 sampleR = samples[i+1];
    // check if amplitude of sample is > amplitudeThreshold
    if (abs(sampleL) > amplitudeThreshold || abs(sampleR) > amplitudeThreshold) {
        // set samples and increase to next sample set
        samples[currentSampleIndex] = sampleL;
        samples[currentSampleIndex+1] = sampleR;
        currentSampleIndex+=channels;
    }
}

// how many bytes should be in non-amplitudeThreshold samples
int bytesToCopy = currentSampleIndex * sizeof(SInt16);

if (bytesToCopy > 0) {
    // store samples in circular buffer
    TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&circularBuffer, samples, bytesToCopy);
} else {
    // set buffer to silence
    memset((SInt16*)inIoData->mBuffers[0].mData, 0, bytesToCopy);
    return noErr;
}

int outputDataByteSize = inIoData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;
SInt16 *outputBuffer = (SInt16*)inIoData->mBuffers[0].mData;

// if circularBuffer is filled more than outputDataByteSize * 10 (large buffer)
if (circularBuffer.fillCount > outputDataByteSize * 10) {

    int32_t availableBytes;
    SInt16 *buffer = TPCircularBufferTail(&circularBuffer, &availableBytes);
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"circular buffer is empty. end of track.");
        return noErr;
    }

    int numBytes = MIN(bytesToCopy, availableBytes);
    memcpy(outputBuffer, buffer, numBytes);

    // consume (remove) bytes from circular buffer that are being copied to output buffer
    TPCircularBufferConsume(&circularBuffer, numBytes);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"buffering");
    memset(targetBuffer, 0, outputDataByteSize);
    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the silence detection logic (I am not an IOS/swift programmer), it seems that you are defining silence on a sample by sample basis. This is not how audio works, and essentially all you will do is cut the part of the waveform that is lower than amplitudeThreshold - resulting in clicks and,because the upper part of the waveform still exists, the silence/low amplitude data is still somewhat there (although corrupted).

I would suggest calculating the amplitude of a *frame* of audio, i.e some subset of samples, and instead of hard cutting to 0 put in a linear ramp up/down to remove clicks.

Also another point, what format are your samples in? -1 : 1 PCM? It would also be worth detecting silence based on decibels rather than raw data if you have not done this already.

Comment: The samples are LPCM. The logic for detecting/skipping samples seems to work now (though could maybe be better?). The clicks/pops I would occasionally get seems to be due to the circular buffer not being large enough and therefore the audio was stopping too often (causing a click) while the buffer would fill up enough to play. Increasing the buffer size seemed to smooth this out. I have to test it some more, but it seems it might be working ok now. On iOS, my understanding is mono 1 frame = 1 sample and stereo 1 frame is 2 samples. So in my example, I believe I'm using frames already, right?